# How to sort by the first element of the array in mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

How can I sort the items by the first element in the array?
Here is the example, the authors is an array list, and I want that the list is sorted by the first element.

```
"authors":"[John Doe, Mark Miller]"
```

I tried like below, but doesn't work.

```
db.collection('books')
    .find()
    .sort({ "authors[0]": 1 })
```

Answer (score 0):

What you tried is working with small modification as follow:

```
db.collection('books')
.find()
.sort({ "authors.0": 1 })
```

And if collection is big it is best to improve performance with index as follow:

```
db.books.createIndex({"authors.0":1})
```